# Is it possible to ping to an interface that is a part of a Linux bridge?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, virtual-machines

My goal is to connect a virtual machine A with a virtual machine C through a virtual machine B that has two interfaces. When I create a bridge on these two interfaces I can ping A<-->C but I cannot ping from A<-->B and B<-->C. If the bridge works in layer 2, is it possible to ping to interfaces that are part of the bridge?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.
If you're not getting this, please take a look at firewall rules.

It's a virtual interface, but it's still an interface and supposed to work following networks and TCP/IP standards.

Edit:
About firewall rules, if you're using Linux, you're supposed to confirm that iptables allows routing and ping to and from both networks and interfaces.

If you're using Ubuntu, check if there's any rule blocking or allowing traffic to its IP and network
If you're using RedHat/CentOS, take a look to firewall
If you're using Windows, check Windows Defender and confirm traffic are allowed for private networks

Comment: Somewhat relevant to note, it is possible to ping interfaces that share a bridge *if those interfaces have IP addresses*.

Comment: @surfingonthenet Could you write something more about "looking at firewall rules"?

Comment: @user6758 edited on the post